# Deny rapid access to the website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an Asp.Net MVC 5.1 website. Some people have wrote some bots to download the whole website and worse than that, they don't stop. I was wondering how can I deny access to any action on the website if it's being accessed too fast. By "too fast" I mean a speed which is humanly impossible. For instance once every second. I think this is a common problem for any website. Which is the recommended way to do achieve such restriction?

PS: My website is on a VPS and I have full access to IIS if there's a way to do this there.

Comment: Are you sure the bots downloading your whole website aren't google or bing bots? Also this is why sites put "© 2014 My Company" on the bottom of every page. (This does not constitute legal advise.)

Comment: I doubt there's a good way to accomplish this. If you make your site available, then bots can read the site. Bots can be slowed down to human speed so that they're undetectable if the bot operator wishes. If you're worried about a Denial of Service attack, then look up info about that. I don't think Denial of Service attacks really fall under the scope of Stack Overflow since it's not a programming issue.

Comment: @TimothyShields That's a valid point. I don't and haven't looked for it.

Comment: Only way to detect very fast access to certain actions on a page would be with Javascript, which a bot will likely bypass anyway. Fast form submissions and POSTS falls into the territory of DoS attacks. Nothing can really stop anyone from downloading the entire HTML source of a page, considering that that's what your browser does anyway.

Comment: @mason Thanks. Actually right now I was searching for DOS attacks and ways to prevent them. Do you know any good ways to do it?

Comment: No, that would be a good question for [Network Engineering](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: @ElGavilan: I don't think he means "fast" in the sense of download speed, but rather rapidity of the requests. And that is detectable from the server-side.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Exactly. I thought I was clear on that. Thanks for clarifying it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use an `HttpModule`, you can filter each request that comes in before it hits any of your actions or anything.

However, you're going to run into a plethora of issues which may make your attempts cause more harm than good.

1. Whenever a browser loads a page, it also loads the resources associated with that page. Are you willing to risk the possibility of breaking images and CSS on your website?
2. Search engines exhibit the behavior you've described. Do you not want your website to be searchable?
3. What criteria do you use to determine whether it's the same entity trying to download the various pages on your site? If you use IP address, that will work against some bots, but it'll also work against people who are using a shared internet connection with other people accessing your site at the same time. And more sophisticated bots will use tricks to get around this.

So you've got to consider the key question: what is the harm caused by these bots scanning your website?

1. If they're hammering your server, then the behavior is more consistent with a denial-of-service attack, in which case you should read up on how to prevent those.
2. If they're taking your copyrighted data and displaying it on their own websites without your permission, then you may want to consider legal options, or reporting their abuse to search engines so they don't enjoy success from the fruits of your labors.
3. If it's "none of the above" then you should probably just ignore them.

Comment: you need to elaborate more on the 1st point you make, why will it break images and css or other resources

Comment: @No1_Melman: If you use a common filter that checks *all* the requests made to your system, then you need to recognize that browsers request these resources *immediately* after downloading the page that references them. (In fact, in some cases they download them before finishing the original request, and they download multiple files concurrently.) So simply refusing to serve more than one request per second is going to mean that people get the content of your pages, and then all the CSS, Javascript, and Images don't load because you deny those requests.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using a custom class which takes advantage of this method. I tried to consider all the points you made in your answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to IIS (at least v7) try this:

Go to "IP Address and Domain Restrictions", and then (in the right side) select "Edit Dynamic Restriction Settings".

Then you can Deny IP Address based on the number of request over a period of time and/or the number of concurrent request.

So if someone connects to you (for example) 20 times in less than a second, it will Deny the access to that IP Address automatically.

If you don't see it, maybe you need to install that module, [instructions here](http://www.hrzdata.com/node/46).